# Magento 2.4.6 Deprecated Functionality: Creation of dynamic property

Tags: magento2.4.6, php8.2

I try to solve this error:

> main.CRITICAL: Deprecated Functionality: Creation of dynamic property
> VENDOR\MODULE\Model\RedsysFactory::$helper is deprecated in
> /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/Model/FILE.php
> on line 71 [] [] main.ERROR: Please provide payment for the order. []
> []
>
> LINE 71 SAID:     $this->helper = $helper;

I try to use this code:

```
    /**
 * Use the fully-qualified AllowDynamicProperties, otherwise the #[AllowDynamicProperties] attribute on "MyClass" WILL NOT WORK.
 */
use \AllowDynamicProperties;

#[AllowDynamicProperties]
class MyClass
{
```

but don´t work

Any idea

Comment: hi dear, can you share the full code?

Answer (score 0):

Define the helper class like this

```
<?php
namespace ....

use Vendor\Modulename\Helper\Data;


class MyClass
{
    protected $helper;
    
    
    public function __construct(
        Data $helper
    ) {
        $this->helper = $helper;
        
    }
    
}
```